# Como receber pagamento instantâneo com cartão de crédito?

Tags: php, android, api, pagamento-online

Bom, esses dias tive que recusar uma proposta de site e aplicativo, pois necessitavam que possuísse uma forma de pagamento pelo aplicativo/site onde deveria ser aprovado de maneira instantânea, para que já fosse entregue o pedido. Estava trabalhando com o pagseguro utilizando checkout transparente, porém ele [confirma o pagamento em](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/atendimento/perguntas_frequentes/categoria/como-comprar/prazo-de-compensacao/qual-e-o-prazo-para-que-meu-pagamento-seja-compensado.jhtml#rmcl):

> Cartão de Crédito – em até 2 dias úteis após o pagamento, podendo se
>   estender

E pesquisando um pouco mais, vi o [mercadopago](https://www.mercadopago.com.br/ajuda/meios-de-pagamento-compradores_474), que para cartão de crédito diz ser instantânea a aprovação.
Gostaria de saber se existe outra alternativa para pagamento instantâneo

Comment: Tem o PayPal, é instantâneo (tirando o Cheque Digital!). Na minha opinião ele é o melhor de todos, tem vários modos de implementar, é usado e suportado por vários países (alguns tem recursos diferentes), por mim bem melhor do que o resto (PagSeguro, MercadoPago). Ele aprova o pagamento na hora ou dará um erro ao usuário, simples assim. O vendedor (titular do PayPal) vai receber o dinheiro imediatamente também, não há qualquer "saldo pendente" como no MercadoPago, exceto se o PayPal acreditar que seu negocio é de risco (dai pode limitar X% para ficar retido por X dias).

Comment: Isso depende muito da operadora e de como é feito este controle por ela. Se o cliente tiver dinheiro em conta o pagamento é confirmado na hoje. Pelo menos com a cielo é assim. Existe um exemplo pronto que funcionamento exatamente da forma como precisa. Dá uma olhada neste link: 

https://datafacilinformatica.com.br/script-em-php-para-pagamento-com-cartao-de-creditos/

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Pagamento instantâneo será um pouco difícil conseguir, pois por segurança os sistemas de pagamentos (chamados também de gateway) adotam algumas medidas de segurança que ajudam a manter a compra e venda segura, isso poderá levar de alguns minutos à algumas horas, pois dependendo do titular e informações do cartão poderá ser necessário uma confirmação via chamada telefônica ou SMS.

Já utilizo PagSeguro e tenho pagamentos via cartão quase que aprovados de forma imediato (leva cerca de minutos), o prazo de 2 dias úteis é "ATÉ" conforme mencionado por você:
"Cartão de Crédito – em até 2 dias úteis após o pagamento, podendo se estender"

Não significa que será 2 dias úteis, e sim que pode ocorrer ATÉ 2 dias úteis, Paypal adota uma medida semelhante, em outras palavras para vendas online o melhor que você conseguirá é confirmação em minutos (não na hora infelizmente)

Answer (score 1):

No Brasil não tem nenhuma empresa de pagamento eletrônico que faça isso! Eles sempre pedem 2 dias seja o Paypal, MercadoPago, Pagueseguro e mesmo a Bcash/Payu! Porque alem de verificar se o cartão utilizado não é clonado ou fraudado qualquer transação que envolva cartão até passar da adm do cartão para a instituição financeira leva de 24 a 48 horas!